# Cant set a JTextField as an int

Tags: java, swing, casting, jtextfield

When I use `setText()` on the textfield it wont allow me to do so because what i want in there is an `int`, i would change the int to a string but int's are needed to do further calculations.

How can I get set the text of a `JTextField` with an `int`.

```
private void setAllTextFields(MenuItem m){
        desBox.setText(m.getDescriptions());
        priceTF.setText(m.getPrice());
        calsTF.setText(m.getCalories());
    }
```

price and calories are the numbers

thanks

Comment: You can `parse` a `String`...`Integer.parseInt("5");`

Comment: You must display them as strings. You can always parse them back out to int to do calculations

Comment: sorted it now thanks for all the replies

Comment: @cricket_007 *"You must display them as strings. You can always parse them back out to int to do calculations"* Better still, use an int based `SpinnerNumberModel` in a `JSpinner` and keep the input/output values as integer!

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm not too well-versed in the Swing library, but would that work for a `JTextField`? I thought a Spinner was like a dropdown option.

Comment: *"I thought a Spinner was like a dropdown option."* That's a `JComboBox`. A spinner has little up/down arrows beside the field that allow the value to be incremented or decremented. For an example of what spinners look like (and how to use them) see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556)..

Answer (score 2):

You could take number input using `JFormattedTextField` as follows:

```
JFormattedTextField numberField 
   = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance());

//get value from text field
double d = ((Number)numberField.getValue()).doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could parse each time you read the value :

```
// set :
priceTF.setText(String.valueOf(m.getPrice()));

// get :
int value = Integer.parseInt(priceTF.getText());
```